# cannot init a class object : objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, init

I'm trying to make a simple subclass of CCNode, but I can't create the object.

It gives me the error "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[ContentPane<0x206898> init]: cannot init a class object.'"

Here is my subclass of CCNode:

```
#import "ContentPane.h"

@implementation ContentPane{
    int content[8][4];
    CCSprite *_rockPath1;
    CCSprite *_rockPath2;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        CCLOG(@"ContentPane created");
    }

    return self;
}
```

@end

Here is where I try to initiate it:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    // tell this scene to accept touches
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    _counter = 0;
    ContentPane *pane = [ContentPane init];
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Couple things,

In Obj-c when you want to initialize an Object, you need to allocate space for it.
That is done using the `alloc` keyword.

so your `ContentPane *pane = [ContentPane init];`

turns into  `ContentPane *pane = [[ContentPane alloc] init];`

Also, whatever tutorial you are following, Stop... the way you have declared your variables we call them (iVars) is a very old fashioned way of doing things, they should really be properties. and `Boolean` values are represented by `YES` and `NO` not `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: Do I have to deallocate my objects later on? I'm confused by what the ARC does and doesn't handle.

Comment: sure, [Beginning iOS programming by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) is a really good resource. And any book that is less then a year old will really help too. Objective-c has matured a lot since the "old" days. ARC you generally do not have to worry about, IF you are using properties, properties do  a lot for you for free. ARC (automatic reference counting) is exactly that, if a property is marked as `Strong` then it will increment the reference count, When that count becomes zero, your object will be free'd

Answer (score 1):

If you are here just like me wondering  why you code is crashing.

```
 [NSArray init];
```

should be :

```
[[NSArray alloc] init];
```

or

```
[NSArray array];
```

You crash could caused by any other class here NSArray here is for reference only.